# Loop click function to show and hide div

Tags: jquery, click

What's the easiest way to loop the click function below?

```
$('#botao-expandir').click(function () {
        $('#clipping-content').show();
        $(this).text('Reduzir');
        $(this).addClass('botao-reduzir');
        $('.botao-reduzir').click(function () {
            $('#clipping-content').hide();
            $(this).text('Expandir');
            $(this).removeClass('botao-reduzir');
        });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean loop the click function? Do you realize every time you click on $('#botao-expandir') you add multiple click events to the other elements!

Comment: I just want one div to be clicked to show and hide another div continuosly.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you may be overthinking this a bit. I don't know if you are trying to do animations or not but a toggle function is what you are looking for.

Try this:

```
$('#botao-expandir').click(function(){ 
    $('#clipping-content').slideToggle(); 
});
```

Give that a shot!

UPDATE (another way to accomplish the same thing):

```
<script>
    .botao-hide {
     display:none;
     visibility:hidden;
     }
</script>

$('#botao-expandir').click(function(){ 
    $('#clipping-content').toggleClass("botao-hide"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for infinite looping you can use the setInterval function as the following;

```
function fooloop() {
$('#botao-expandir').click(function () {
   $('#clipping-content').show();
   $(this).text('Reduzir');
   $(this).addClass('botao-reduzir');
   $('.botao-reduzir').click(function () {
        $('#clipping-content').hide();
        $(this).text('Expandir');
        $(this).removeClass('botao-reduzir');
     });
});
}
setInterval(fooloop, 2000);
```

EDIT: OK I see the updated Comment, then recommend you to use the toggle function!

```
$('#botao-expandir').click(function(){ 
    $('#clipping-content').slideToggle(); 
});
```

Comment: You are just adding click events every 2 seconds.

Comment: he's asking for loop and i give him an loop, now i have seen that he woul show/hide, and now i say he should use the toggle!

Comment: It works fine, but I'm not quite sure if this is gonna work separately in case I have many div classes instead of id's, does it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help guys! It didn't solve 100% of my problem, but I'm half the way! Cheers!!!

Comment: you need the id, that you can access the object